# preferred location for web app files, outside of /var/www

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, web

I am very new to Linux, and I just installed Ubuntu. It really is exciting and I already installed my own apache and mysql. 
The server is running.

I have my website's files under `/var/www` but some files are excluded from user access. In my windows environment I put them under `C:/Special` and I wish to know where I should put them under Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: Please put the last part in a separate question, "while at it" is one of the worst things you can do here, it will let people not find your question (and people might complain ;) )

Comment: It really depends on your desired security setup. Is this a single-user server that is only being used to host websites that you administer? Or is this a shared server that lots of different people have access to and need to be able to host their own individual websites? And is there any reason why you need to give non-admin users access to server configuration files (which I presume are the files _excluded from user access_)?

Comment: For now, this is just a test server. I want to deploy my website and test it on a real Linux environment. The website is supposed to be for the public to use. I might use a virtual server or simply my own server in the future, but I know that for both cases I should have a root access to the system.

Comment: "Excluded from user access" - do you mean no one should be able to see them through Apache? Why are they there to begin with? Specify the nature of the files, it is unclear at the moment.

Comment: Somewhere under /var/www IS the preferred location. You can change permissions there if you want to. That's what I do. `chown -R me /var/www`.